# VBA automation error - Invalid forward reference

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that has been running just fine, however, suddenly I am getting the following error:
[image]

I get the error in all the old files as well, even after completely shutting down excel. I also tried adding "AccessibilityCplAdmin 1.0 Type Library", which helped at first but doesn't anymore.

The error is in line "dData(dr, 1) = sheet.Name"

Does anyone know how this could be solved?

```
Sub ListSheets()

    'Call NewFileTabs
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Const ProcName As String = "ListSheets"
    Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow
    Dim IsSuccess As Boolean
    'On Error GoTo ClearError

    'Define locations of where to write
    Const dName As String = "Engine"
    Const dfcAddress As String = "A1" 'where to write old file tabs
    Const dfcAddress_new_file As String = "B1" 'where to write new file tabs
    
    Dim wb_macro As Workbook: Set wb_macro = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws_macro As Worksheet: Set ws_macro = wb_macro.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim macro_filename As String: macro_filename = wb_macro.Name
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = ws_macro.Range(dfcAddress) 'where to write old tabs
    Dim dCell_new As Range: Set dCell_new = ws_macro.Range(dfcAddress_new_file) 'where to write new tabs
    
    Dim sFolderPath As String: sFolderPath = wb_macro.Path & "\"
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Dim wb_from As Workbook
    Dim new_wb As Workbook
    Dim sheet As Object
    Dim sht_new As Object
    Dim sFilePath As String
    Dim sFilePath_newfile As String
    Dim dData As Variant
    Dim dData_1 As Variant
    Dim NewTemplate As Variant
    Dim from_nr_sheet As Long
    Dim nr_sheet_new_file As Long
    Dim dr As Long
    Dim dr_new As Long
    
    Dim miss_tab As String
    
    'Get the list of new file tabs (column B)
    
    NewTemplate = Application.GetOpenFilename
    
    If NewTemplate <> False Then
        
        Set new_wb = Workbooks.Open(NewTemplate)
        Dim new_wb_name As String: new_wb_name = new_wb.Name
        Dim sFolderPath_new As String: sFolderPath_new = new_wb.Path & "\"
        Dim sFileName_new As String: sFileName_new = Dir(sFolderPath_new & "*.xlsb*")
        sFilePath_newfile = sFolderPath_new & sFileName_new
        nr_sheet_new_file = new_wb.Sheets.Count + 1
        ReDim dData_1(1 To nr_sheet_new_file, 1 To 1)
        dData_1(1, 1) = sFilePath_newfile
        dr_new = 1
        For Each sht_new In new_wb.Sheets
            dr_new = dr_new + 1
            dData_1(dr_new, 1) = sht_new.Name
        Next sht_new
        'new_wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Range(dCell_new, dCell_new.Offset(UBound(dData_1, 1) - 1)) = dData_1
        End If
    IsSuccess = True
        
    'Determine all the filepaths in a dedicated loop.
    'If this succeeds, the issue is somewhere else
    'or the other code is somehow preventing 'Dir' from succeeding
    Dim filesOfInterest As Collection
    Set filesOfInterest = New Collection
    
    Dim sFileName As String
    sFileName = Dir(sFolderPath & "*.xlsb*")
    
    Do While Len(sFileName) > 0
        filesOfInterest.Add sFileName
        sFileName = Dir
    Loop
    
    'Get the list of other tabs (column A)
    
    'Operate on all the filepaths
    Dim fileOfInterest As Variant
    For Each fileOfInterest In filesOfInterest
        If StrComp(fileOfInterest, macro_filename, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
            sFilePath = sFolderPath & fileOfInterest
            Set wb_from = Workbooks.Open(sFilePath)
            from_nr_sheet = wb_from.Sheets.Count + 1 ' + 1 for header
            ReDim dData(1 To from_nr_sheet, 1 To 1)
            dData(1, 1) = sFilePath ' sFileName - write header
            dr = 1
            For Each sheet In wb_from.Sheets
                dr = dr + 1
                dData(dr, 1) = sheet.Name
            Next sheet
            dCell.Resize(from_nr_sheet).Value = dData ' write to destination worksheet
            
            'Copy the tabs over
            Workbooks(macro_filename).Sheets("Engine").Activate
            Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("F2:F100")
            Dim cel As Range
            
            For Each cel In rng 'look at first 100 different rows
                 If Not cel.Value = "" Then
                    miss_tab = cel.Value
                    
                    wb_from.Sheets(cel.Value).Copy Before:=Workbooks(new_wb_name).Sheets("Core")
                End If
            Next cel
            
             Call Copy_cells(wb_from, new_wb)
            
            wb_from.Close SaveChanges:=False
            new_wb.SaveAs Filename:=sFolderPath_new & fileOfInterest
            
            Set new_wb = Workbooks.Open(sFilePath_newfile)
            
        End If
        Workbooks(macro_filename).Sheets("Engine").Activate
        Sheets("Engine").Range("A1:A100").ClearContents
   Next

   Sheets("Engine").Range("A1:B100").ClearContents
   new_wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
   RefreshLink_folder (sFolderPath_new)
   
   IsSuccess = True
    Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityByUI
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: *I have a code...*  - post it and point out where the error occurs.

Comment: Hi @KostasK., sorry I did not want to post the code as it is extremely long, and I thought this might be a standard issue. Also the code worked fine before, it suddenly became an issue (even with older unchanged versions of the code)

Comment: No need to post everything, just the part where it fails. It's almost impossible to get help without seeing the code. Have you checked the references are in order and nothing is missing?

Comment: Yes, as I've said the code worked okay. Without any changes it suddenly stopped

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Excel Worksheets break down like this. :(

Steps to fix:

1. Copy the bad worksheet's contents to a new one (remember its name)
2. Delete bad worksheet
3. Rename the new worksheet to the original name.